# Customise AppEngine Image Service Serving Url with type extension

Tags: google-app-engine, flowplayer

What I would like to achieve is to let AppEngine Image Service to generate a serving URL with file type as an extension.

For example, in my local, a serving url may look like:

```
http://0.0.0.0:8898/_ah/img/u4EXyF53eLVd8s5wHrE3tg
```

Is it possible to override it into the form of something like

```
http://0.0.0.0:8898/_ah/img/u4EXyF53eLVd8s5wHrE3tg/filename.jpg
```

The reason I need to do this is I am using Flowplayer and hope to add a splash image by using the playlist function. However, it looks like Flowplayer won't recognize image file without a proper image extension.

Comment: The is no option for a get_serving_url to use an extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is a workaround for the solution.
Basically, you can add a fake query parameter at the end of the url, and Google will treat them the same.

So, for instance, a url `http://0.0.0.0:8898/_ah/img/u4EXyF53eLVd8s5wHrE3tg`, you can make it

`http://0.0.0.0:8898/_ah/img/u4EXyF53eLVd8s5wHrE3tg?.png` or `http://0.0.0.0:8898/_ah/img/u4EXyF53eLVd8s5wHrE3tg?.jpg`

depending on your need. Google won't care about the query parameters, but I got what I need and my client software (Flowplayer) is happy about this new link.

Answer (score 1):

There are no "files" on the web, just resources. And every resource has an Url. The type of the resource is defined by `Content-type` header. There is no such thing as "file type as an extension" on the web.

Image service sets the `Content-type` properly so all standard clients should be able to display it.

Also, it seems that Flowplayer splash images are just a [normal images displayed in HTML](http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/skinning/splash-info.html), so there should be no problem with this.

Can you display your Url normally in HTML?

Comment: Thanks, and I got your point. I understand it's not a file but a resource, that's why I want to hack it somehow to make it looks like a file for some certain software (in this case flowplayer) to understand it.

Comment: In terms of Flowplayer, sorry about the confusion. I'm aware of that normal image display method, however, since I'm using object embed, there is no way for that to work. I should clarify it in the question, my apologies.